# How To inject this kind of class functionality. Spring Open JPA

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, struts2, dependency-injection, openjpa-maven-plugin

How can I inject the class UserProfile in this kind of statement? This is using Struts2 - Spring plugin.

( UserProfile userProfile = em.find(UserProfile.class,"1");) ---> I could don't have any idea how to change this for injection style in spring?

```
package tester;

/**
 *
 * @author god-gavedmework
 */


import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import lotmovement.business.entity.UserProfile;



/**
 *
 * @author god-gavedmework
 */
public class Record_exist {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = 
        Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LotMovementPU");

        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

        EntityTransaction userTransaction = em.getTransaction();
        userTransaction.begin();
        UserProfile userProfile = em.find(UserProfile.class,"1");

        if(userProfile.getUserId().equals("tok"))
        {
            System.out.println("find");
            System.out.println("write successful");
        }


        entityManagerFactory.close();


    }
}
```

My Spring injection that does not work. 
I had injected  UserProfile entity using setters but i think there is a problem because it could not retrieve any data.

```
private UserProfile userProfile; --> it does inject.

entityStart.em.find(UserProfile.class, userId)--> will not work in the sense that no values are retrieved.
```

Complete Class

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package lotmovement.business.crud;

import lotmovement.business.entity.UserProfile;

/**
 *
 * @author god-gavedmework
 */
public class RecordExistUserProfile {

    private EntityStart entityStart;
    private UserProfile userProfile;


    public boolean checkrecordexist(String userId) {
        entityStart.StartDbaseConnection();
        entityStart.em.find(UserProfile.class, userId); ---> this one will not work.

        if (userId.equals(userProfile.getUserId())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean CheckPasswordCorrect(String userId, String password) {
        entityStart.StartDbaseConnection();

        UserProfile up = entityStart.em.find(UserProfile.class, userId); --> this one will work but it is not injected...


        if (password.equals(up.getPassword())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }



    public UserProfile getUserProfile() {
        return userProfile;
    }

    public void setUserProfile(UserProfile userProfile) {
        this.userProfile = userProfile;
    }

    public EntityStart getEntityStart() {
        return entityStart;
    }

    public void setEntityStart(EntityStart entityStart) {
        this.entityStart = entityStart;
    }



}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to inject and where?

Comment: Instead of doing this : UserProfile up = entityStart.em.find(UserProfile.class, userId);

What should be done in srping? @aleksandr M

Comment: What do you want it to be? What do you want to inject exactly!?

Comment: For decoupling.. That is the reason yet I use spring on this program.... or maybe i did not get it?

Comment: I tried to inject the Entity User Profile by this.  

UserProfile userprofile  

however this code does not work. entityStart.em.find(UserProfile.class, userId);

The original code is:
 UserProfile userProfile = em.find(UserProfile.class,userId);
@Aleksandr M Could you understand now?

Comment: Do you want to inject `userId`?

Comment: @AleksandrM no I am injecting the class UserProfile. In struts2 spring plugin, When you do UserProfile userProfile, It will automatically inject it.. Yeah, it injected the class but this (entityStart.em.find(UserProfile.class, userId);) does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the root cause and the solution of the problem.

Root Cause:

UserProfile userProfile; --> it will inject the UserProfile entity.

entityStart.em.find(UserProfile.class, userId); --> This will not work because the it was not passed to the class variable userProfile..

Solution:

UserProfile userProfile; --> inject the UserProfile entity.

userProfile = entityStart.em.find(UserProfile.class, userId);  ---> find() now works find.